# Quartz RescheduleJob is creating me new jobs instead of do as spected

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, quartz

I'm facing an issue with Quartz and  `RescheduleJob` function.
I'm having an email processor queue and I'm making a Reschedule for the unprocessed emails. Emails has a retry count (each one), if the email sent process fails, the retry count increases and the email is enqueue. Each time the processor fires, emails on queue are processed.
The issue fact is that on app starts, new schedule jobs appears on minimal time (1 min) with different instances and it not look the same instance.

In the doc it says:

> Remove (delete) the Quartz.ITrigger with the given key, and store the
>   new give    one - which must be associated with the same job (the new
>   trigger must have the job name & group specified) - however, the new
>   trigger need not have the same  name as the old trigger.

But on my logs it comes:

```
2018-06-21 10:03:21,201 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] INFO  Services.BaseService [(null)] - Email Send error. Contact Form | To:esddaada@test.com Subject: Thank You for Contacting. Email moved to Send Queue.
2018-06-21 10:04:05,177 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] WARN  Services.EmailJob [(null)] - EmailJob Time elapsed updated to 2 mins.
2018-06-21 10:04:07,874 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] INFO  Services.BaseService [(null)] - Email Send error. Contact Form | To:esddaada@test.com Subject: Thank You for Contacting Us. Email moved to Send Queue.
2018-06-21 10:04:59,900 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] WARN  Services.EmailJob [(null)] - EmailJob Time elapsed updated to 4 mins.
2018-06-21 10:05:03,595 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3] INFO  Services.BaseService [(null)] - Email Send error. Contact Form | To:esddaada@test.com Subject: Thank You for Contacting Us. Email moved to Send Queue.
2018-06-21 10:05:08,439 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3] WARN  Services.EmailJob [(null)] - EmailJob Time elapsed updated to 6 mins.
2018-06-21 10:05:11,155 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4] INFO  Services.BaseService [(null)] - Email Send error. Contact Form | To:esddaada@test.com Subject: Thank You for Contacting Us. Email moved to Send Queue.
2018-06-21 10:05:18,871 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4] WARN  Services.EmailJob [(null)] - EmailJob Time elapsed updated to 8 mins.
2018-06-21 10:05:22,539 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5] INFO  Services.BaseService [(null)] - Email Send error. Contact Form | To:esddaada@test.com Subject: Thank You for Contacting Us. Email moved to Send Queue.
2018-06-21 10:05:22,551 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5] ERROR Services.EmailJob [(null)] - Email on Queue Reach max 6 send retry Times! Application: To:esddaada@test.com Subject:Thank You for Contacting Us.
```

This is my code:

```
public static void StartEmailJob() // scheduler called on Application_Start()
    {

        var scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

        var emailJob = JobBuilder.Create<EmailJob>().Build();

        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("EmailJob", "group1")
           // .StartAt(DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(1))
            .WithSimpleSchedule(sh => sh
                .WithIntervalInMinutes(RetryInterval)
                .RepeatForever())
            .Build();
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(emailJob, trigger);

        scheduler.Start();

    }


[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
    public class EmailJob : IJob
    {
      public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
       {
            var retryCount = 5;

         var emailsQueue = context.Emails;
            if (emailsQueue.Any(ml => ml.RetryCount < retryCount))
            {
                var emails = emailsQueue .Where(ml => ml.RetryCount < retryCount);

                var count = emails.FirstOrDefault().RetryCount;

                foreach (var email in emails)
                {
                    if (!EmailService.SendEmail(email, out string error))
                    {

                        if (email.RetryCount >= retryCount)
                        {
                            Logger.Error($"Email on Queue Reach max {retryCount} send retry Times!");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       //remove email from queue
                    }
                }


                try
                {
                    RescheduleJob(context, count, true);
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Logger.Error("EmailJob RescheduleJob Error!", exc);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    RescheduleJob(context, 0, true);
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Logger.Error("EmailJob RescheduleJob Error!", exc);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void RescheduleJob(IJobExecutionContext jobContext,  int retryCount, bool startsNow)
    {
        var retryInterval = 5;

        var scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        // get the trigger

        var intervalReminder = (retryCount == 0 ? 1 : retryCount) * retryInterval;

        var triggerBuilder = jobContext.Trigger.GetTriggerBuilder();

        //crerates a new trigger with the old one
        var newTrigger = triggerBuilder.WithSimpleSchedule(s => s
            .WithIntervalInMinutes(intervalReminder)
            .RepeatForever())
            .Build();

        if (newTrigger is ISimpleTrigger simpleTrigger)
        {
            if (jobContext.JobInstance is ISimpleTrigger trigger)
                (newTrigger as ISimpleTrigger).TimesTriggered = trigger.TimesTriggered;
        }

        // reschedule the job with a new trigger
        scheduler.RescheduleJob(jobContext.Trigger.Key, newTrigger);
        Logger.Warn($"EmailJob Time elapsed updated to {intervalReminder} mins.");

    }
    }
```

The weird thing is that after a time, when the retry time exhausted, it works as expected. Why? I don't know.

Can someone help me? 
Thank you.

Comment: I'm new to Quartz too, and using Quartz 3.  However, the problem might be your DisallowConcurrentExecution attribute.  That only allows a single instance of that jobkey to run.  When you reschedule, your jobkey and triggerkey are the same.  Try changing the jobkey and triggerkey and simply schedule a new job.

Comment: @bschulz This comes in the documentation:
Remove (delete) the Quartz.ITrigger with the given key, and store the new give one - which must be associated with the same job (the new trigger must have the job name & group specified) - however, the new trigger need not have the same name as the old trigger.
So, theoretically the **RescheduleJob** will do this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I change the code to use another column and store the next date retry interval. I remove `RescheduleJob` and when I check

```
 var retryIntervals = new[] { 15, 25, 45, 60, 93, 110, 150 };     
var emails = emailsQueue .Where(ml => ml.RetryCount < retryCount && ml.NextTimeRetry <= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
```

I also change this part to take into consideration that the retry time must be changed

```
if (!EmailService.SendEmail(email, out string error))
                    {
email.NextTimeRetry = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(retryIntervals[email.RetryCount]);

                        if (email.RetryCount >= retryCount)
                        {
                            Logger.Error($"Email on Queue Reach max {retryCount} send retry Times!");
                        }
                    }
```

For now nobody answer this question but it is good to people know how to deal with this issues.